# Is linear regression a special case of polynomial regression

Tags: regression

Can we say that linear regression is a case of polynomial regression where the biggest nth degree polynomial is 1 ?

Comment: Obviously yes. Just take the coefficients of the higher order terms to be zero

Answer (score 1):

While it may not be wrong to say that linear regression is a special case of polynomial regression, you seem to think that linear regression is about linear combinations of the data.

The 'linear' in linear regression (or linear model) refers to linear combinations of *the regression parameters*. So polynomial regression, linear regression, spline models, and analysis of variance are all just linear models.

Answer (score 1):

Other way around: Polynomial regression is a special case of linear regression.

The *linear* in linear regression refers to linearity in the parameters.  The function $f(\beta) = X\beta$ is linear because $f(c\beta + \alpha) = cf(\beta)+ f(\alpha) \, \forall \alpha, \beta$.

It doesn't matter what $X$ is.  It could be two column matrix (one column of 1s for the intercept) or it could be a basis expansion.  The function is still linear in the parameters.